# How to use eloquent with json data?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a users table with church, branch and group columns. The church and branch columns are integers while the group column is json since one user can belong to many groups but only one church and branch. I am using eloquent to fetch the details of a user. I can only fetch church and branch since only one integer is available in the database. For groups, null is received. I have this query

```
$member = User::where('id',$id)->with(['church','branch', 'group'])->first()->toArray();
```

When I `dd($member);` I receive the following response

```
  array:13 [▼
  "id" => 4
  "name" => "Arjun Stanton"
  "email" => "jake.schmeler@example.org"
  "email_verified_at" => "2021-10-17T07:23:56.000000Z"
  "role" => "Tresurer"
  "church_id" => 1
  "branch_id" => 1
  "group_id" => "["7","9"]"
  "created_at" => "2021-10-17T07:23:57.000000Z"
  "updated_at" => "2021-10-17T07:31:38.000000Z"
  "church" => array:5 [▼
    "id" => 1
    "created_by" => 1
    "name" => "St. Joseph"
    "created_at" => "2021-10-17T07:25:25.000000Z"
    "updated_at" => "2021-10-17T07:25:25.000000Z"
  ]
  "branch" => array:5 [▼
    "id" => 1
    "name" => "Lee Glenn"
    "church_id" => 1
    "created_at" => "2021-10-17T07:25:39.000000Z"
    "updated_at" => "2021-10-17T07:25:39.000000Z"
  ]
  "group" => null
]
```

How to I get the records using the group_id in the database?

Comment: Why are you using JSON when Eloquent supports the [one to many](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many) and it’s inverse [belongs to](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-inverse) relationships?

Comment: @Peppermintology The column contains the id's of all the groups the user belongs to, so I saved them as JSON. The user can belong to more than one group but can only belong to one church and one branch.

Comment: Yup, a `one-to-many` relationship is quite common and doesn't require you to store all `many` related `id`s in a single column.

Answer (score 0):

It is wrong relation you have to use many to many for this kind of relations.
And then you can consider that the result is always an array of 2 elements.
Then you can wrap the result in ResourceClass and get the church as

```
'church' => $this->groups[0],
'branch' => $this->groups[1]
```